# bash scripting , loop not looping

Tags: loops, while-loop

I wrote a while loop to search inside files and append the output to a text file , but it seems like it's reading only the first line of that text file . How do I fix it ?

```
while read line
do
x=`echo $line`
y=`grep $x: /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3`
grep $y /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1 >> users
grep $y /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 4 | tr "," "\n" >> users
done < filename
```

Comment: what does `filename` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to wrap `$x` and `$y` in quotes, as otherwise `grep` may interpret anything after the first space as the name of the file to be searched:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                    

while read line
do
    x=`echo $line`
    y=`grep "$x:" /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3`
    grep "$y" /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1 >> users
    grep "$y" /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 4 | tr "," "\n" >> users
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit safer as some of the grep statements may pick up the wrong fields (i.e. it does not check for the correct field):

```
while read GROUP
do
  GROUP_ID=`grep ^$GROUP: /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f 3`

  USER_ENT=`grep -e '\(.*:\)\{3\}'$GROUP_ID':' /etc/passwd`
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && cut -d ":" -f 1 <<<$USER_ENT

  GROUP_ENT=`grep -e '\(.*:\)\{2\}'$GROUP_ID':' /etc/group`
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && cut -d ":" -f 4 <<<$GROUP_ENT | tr "," "\n" | grep -v ^$

done < $FILE_NAME | sort | uniq >users
```